# Bootstrap Framework align fluid content with normal container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full width layout on my homepage which looks like this:

```
image text
text image
image text
...
```

for that I use the Bootstrap Framework. But I also have normal content with a fixed width. I want to align the contents of those rows. I Created a fiddle so you can see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/87ppykcr/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/1920/800/?random">
</div>
<div style="border-right:1px solid red;" class="col-md-6">
<h1>Align This to right</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So the last row with the title `Align this to right` should be aligned with the content above it but its wider that that. Is there a way to limit it with css?

Comment: Why are you using two different classes? Per bootstrap, *Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.* The behavior you're seeing is the expected behavior. Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

Comment: But what If I want one section to be full width? I cant use `.container` then...but I still want the contents to align on the sides

Comment: You want it full width but also align the sides? So it's not full width?

Comment: Exactly! Well the one column is full width and the other is aligned